# Why is it bringing the Userid back and not the text_max?

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

Hi so im having a problem where when I try to use this command its  bringing the USERID instead of what im trying to get heres the error

File "goonie.py", line 421, in spam
spammers =  users[str(ctx.author.id)]['text_max']
KeyError: '932428536176848938'

The numbers are the "ctx.author.id" and im trying to get the "text_max"

````
async def spam(ctx, message,amount):
  users = await get_paid_data()
  spammers =  users[str(ctx.author.id)]['text_max']

  if amount > spammers:
    if str(ctx.author.id) in users:
        if users[str(ctx.author.id)]['vip'] == 'Y':
           timeleft = datetime.strptime(users[str(ctx.author.id)]['expDate'],'%Y-%m-%d') - datetime.now()
           if timeleft.days <= 0:
                em = discord.Embed(color=0x000000, description="Sorry your plan on this tool has expired")
                await ctx.send(embed=em) ```
````

Comment: You checked it *after* you tried to access it. Are you sure that `str(ctx.author.id)` is actually in the keys of `users`?

Answer (score 0):

`users` is a dictionary.

You first access the `str(ctx.author.id)` key in the dictionary.

The error is telling you the dictionary does not contain a key corresponding to the value of string value of `ctx.author.id`. Therefore, you cannot access `text_max` because the first part of your dict navigation is incorrect.

You should print `users` and see what it contains:

```py
print(users)
```

My initial guess is that you're converting the id to a string when it in-fact doesn't need to be converted, but it's impossible to say without seeing the contents of the dictionary.